# Как наиболее корректно реализовать mutex со счетчиком?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, mutex

Пусть, например, задача - ограничить количество одновременно работающих потоков. Т.е. хочется иметь мьютекс, который бы могли захватывать одновременно `N` потоков, а остальные бы ждали, пока один из потоков не освободит такой мьютекс.

Вижу несколько вариантов организации такой функциональности, например, с использованием переменной для подсчета и обычных мьютексов, но что-то мне кажется, что я изобретаю велосипед.

Как наиболее корректно реализовать такой семафор со счетчиком средствами стандартного C++11? (Или там это уже есть, и я просто плохо читал литературу?..)

Comment: Вопрос я думаю не в языке а в операционной системе. есть ли у вас posix семафоры, начинающиеся с функции sem_init. Или семафоры system v - semget, semop, semctl. Они как раз на это и расчитаны. первый процесс выставит семафор например в значение 5, после чего каждый поток будет уменьшаеть его значение на 1. Как только какой то процесс попытается сделать его  отрицательным он будет заблочен системой до тех пор пока кто то не увеличит значение

Comment: То, что вы хотите получить называется _дроссель_, а процесс - _дросселирование_, у Харта, в "Системном программировании" по этому поводу есть хорошая глава с примерами. Да, дроссель реализуется с помощью семафора. В `С++11` нет семафоров, они тут реализуются атомарным счетчиком, или используйте готовый, который предоставляет Ваша `OS`. В `Windows`, например: это `CreateSemaphore/ReleaseSemaphore/WaitFor[Single/Multiple]Object[s]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В стандартной библиотеке готового семафора нет, по этому его надо писать самому, делая ожидание на `condition_variable`.

В простейшем варианте это

```
class Semaphore {
public:
    explicit Semaphore(int max_count) : max_count_(max_count) {}

    void acquire() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut_);
        while (count_ == max_count_) cv_.wait(lock);
        ++count_;
    }

    void release() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut_);
        assert(count_ > 0);
        --count_;
        cv_.notify_one();
    }

private:
    int max_count_;
    int count_ = 0;
    std::mutex mut_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
};
```

Вызов `notify` в `release()` можно вынести из под мьютекса. Но на некоторых реализациях [это не нужно](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one).

Вместо мьютекса в `release()` можно использовать атомарную переменную `count_`, но это потребует CAS в `acquire()`. Код усложнится, а выигрыш в производительности надо еще доказать.

Comment: Считаете, что в `release()` имеет смысл разрешать делать `_count` отрицательным?

Comment: А может просто проверять? Ну, assert можно по желанию макрогенерацией добавлять. (кстати, поздравляю с 10К)

Comment: Может путаю, но помнится в posix семафорах лишний POST ни на что не влияет.

Comment: @Abyx А можно в двух словах об `unique_lock` - почему именно он использован? И - я верно понимаю принцип действия: первые N потоков, грубо говоря, быстро проскакивают увеличение счетчика, потом один застряет на ожидании `cv_.wait`, остальные - на мьютексе? тогда в чем смысл проверки в цикле `while (count_ == max_count_)`, а не просто с `if`?